# Replace previous equations into the current one in a recurrence relation

Tags: evaluation, linear-algebra, difference-equations

I have a recurrence relation given as follows:

```
f[k + 1] == 1/a[k, k + 1] Sum[a[k, k - k1] f[k - k1], {k1,0,k-1}]
```

Evaluating it for `k = 1`, we obtain

```
f[2] == a[1, 1]/a[1, 2] f[1]
```

Substituting it into the expression for `f[3]`, we will express it in terms of `f[1]`. Generally, `f[k]` is expressed solely in terms of `f[1]`.

On the other hand, I am given the restriction

```
Sum[f[k], {k, 1, Ka}] == 1
```

So, the basic idea is to express all of `f[1]`, `f[2]`, ..., `f[k]` and substitute them into the above restriction and solve it for `f[1]` and then find all other `f[2]`, ..., `f[Ka]`.

My idea was to define the first equation as a rule

```
rule[1]=f[2]->a[1,1]/a[1,2]f[1];
```

Then, store the system in a table

```
tabeqs = Table[f[k+1] == 1/a[k,k+1] Sum[a[k,k-k1]f[k-k1],{k1,0,k-1}],{k,2,10}];
```

So that

```
tabeqs[[1]]/.{rule[1]}
```

will provide the desired output

```
f[3] == a[2,1]/a[2,3] f[1] + a[1,1] a[2,2] a[3,3] / a[1,2] / a[2,3]f[1]
```

I understand that I need to define

```
rule[2] = tabeqs[[1]]/.{rule[1]}/.Equal->Rule;
```

and repeat the procedure. But I can't make it automatic. Any help and guidance will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use [`FoldPairList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldPairList.html).

With `tabeqs` and `rule[1]` as in OP.

```
sub =
  FoldPairList[
   With[{g = #2 /. Rule @@@ #}
     , {g, Append[#, g]}
     ] &
   , {Equal @@ rule[1]}
   , tabeqs
   ];
```

with first 3 entries

```
sub[[;; 3]] // Column
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

or

```
Simplify[sub[[;; 3]]] // Column
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I need. Is that possible to store the output of `FoldPairList` into an array `f[k]`? I have tried `f[k] /. sub[k]`, but that does not work.

Comment: Yes, `Set @@@ sub;` then `f[4]` for example. However, note that `sub` will then evaluate to `{True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True}` instead of the formulas. `ClearAll[f]` to get them back.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.