# Solve the current equation with respect to one of the coefficients and substitute it into each equation of the system

Tags: matrix, replacement, linear-algebra

Good day to all!

In this question about [recurrence relations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/265138/replace-previous-equations-into-the-current-one-in-a-recurrence-relation/265139?noredirect=1#comment660836_265139), I had a simple case when the `k + 1`th variable is represented in terms of `f[1]`, `f[2]`, ..., `f[k]` as follows:

```
f[k + 1] == 1/a[k, k + 1] Sum[a[k, k - k1] f[k - k1], {k1,0,k-1}]
```

I am now dealing with a more complex system, where in `k`th equation, only the coefficient of `f[k + 1]` is positive and others are negative, providing

```
f[k + 1] == 1/a[k, k + 1] Sum[Abs[a[k, k1]] f[k1], {k1, 1, k-1}]
```

Obviously, in the sum, `k1 != k + 1`.

The procedure I want to perform is similar to the Gauss elimination method. I want to substitute `f[2]` (`k = 1` in the above equation) into the rest of the system and keep that as its first equation. Then, substitute `f[3]` (`f[2]` being already eliminated from it) into the rest of the system including the first equation. Repeating this procedure, all equations should be expressed in terms of `f[1]` only. All unknowns are strictly positive.

So, the first rule will look like

```
indx[k_]:=DeleteCases[Range[1, 20], k + 1];
tabeqs = Table[f[k+1] == 1/a[k, k+1] Sum[Abs[a[k,k1]]f[k1],{k1,indx[k]}],{k,1,20}];
rule[1] = tabeqs[[1]]/.Equal->Rule
```

which needs to be substituted into the whole system:

```
tabeqs/.rule[1]
```

The new system and the second rule will be

```
tabeqs2 = Append[tabeqs[[2;;k2]]/.rule[1],rule[1]/.Rule->Equal];
rule[2] = Solve[tabeqs2[[1]],f[3]][[1]][[1]];
```

And so on. However, I am not able to make this automatic for the whole system. Any guidance is highly appreciated.